# Filter NSArray to make new NSArray for use on tableview methods

Tags: ios, nsarray, nspredicate, uitableview

I have a NSArray that looks like this:

```
{"result":
    [
        {
            "epoch":"1371333600"
        },
        {
            "epoch":"1371420000"
        },
        {
            "epoch":"1371333600"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to sort the NSArray and make a new one so i can use it easier with the tableview methods to count the sections and rows.

**All the dates that are the same need to be in one section.**

The array should look like the example below but i don’t know how to get there. I have tried NSPredicate and used a loop but it won’t work.

What i want:

```
{"result":
    [
        {"data":
            [
                {
                    "epoch":"1371333600"
                },
                {
                    "epoch":"1371333600"
                }
            ]
        },
        {"data":
            [
                {
                    "epoch":"1371420000"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My NSPredicate looks like this, but does not give me the result.

```
_finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"epoch IN %@", [_resultArray valueForKey:@"epoch"]];
_predicateDate = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dataSortArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];

if ([_predicateDate count] != 0) 
    {
        NSDictionary *itemsArrayDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:_predicateDate forKey:@"data"];
        [_finalArray addObject:itemsArrayDict];
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NSOrderedSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is awesome for this occasion as it allows you to get the unique strings.

```
NSDictionary *dict1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"2222222" forKey:@"epoch"];
NSDictionary *dict2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"2222222" forKey:@"epoch"];
NSDictionary *dict3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"1111111" forKey:@"epoch"];

NSArray *dictArray = @[dict1, dict2, dict3];
NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSArray *epoches = [dictArray valueForKey:@"epoch"];
NSOrderedSet *orderedSet = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:epoches];

for (NSString *string in orderedSet) {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"epoch == %@", string];
    NSArray *resultsArray = [dictArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    [finalArray addObject:resultsArray];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the NSPredicate to filter an array like:

```
//NSPredicate to filter an array
NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"hello" forKey:@"Test"]];    
NSArray *filtered = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(Test == %@)", @"hello"]];
```

Thanks

Comment: I know, problem is that i have different epoch times and some are the same. All the same need to be set together in one section. See my example.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using dictionaries along with arrays. Here's what I've achieved:

```
(result 
    (data
            {
        epoch = 1371333600;
    },
            {
        epoch = 1371333600;
    }
),
    (data
            {
        epoch = 1371420000;
    }
)

)
```

I'm not using predicates, but it looks as it's working :). Here is the code:

```
// Initial input
NSArray *result = @[@{@"epoch":@"1371333600"},@{@"epoch":@"1371420000"},@{@"epoch":@"1371333600"}];

// Get unique values for the input
NSSet *resultSet = [NSSet setWithArray:result];

// Here we are going to store the final result
NSMutableArray *newResult = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Loop over the unique items
for (NSDictionary *uniqueItem in resultSet) {

    // Here we are going to store the grouped data
    NSMutableArray *dataResult = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Loop over the initial input
    for (NSDictionary *resultItem in result) {

        // Search for all the items that are equal to the uniqe
        // I would rather include a count instead of repeating values :)
        if([uniqueItem isEqual:resultItem]) {
            [dataResult addObject:resultItem];
        }
    }

    [newResult addObject:dataResult];
}

NSLog(@"%@", newResult);
```

Cheers!